# Plotting dates versus cumulative character values

Tags: r

I have the following data set called `someDat` showing registration date of users:

```
     dates  users
11/06/2013  alfred
12/06/2013  andrew
12/06/2013  john
15/06/2013  jojo
15/06/2013  jeff
15/06/2013  samson
18/06/2013  dave
18/06/2013  hamsa
19/06/2013  kambua
```

Now I'd like to plot dates versus cumulative number of users, as shown in the image. I've tried converting the `users` into factors and then use the function `cumsum` but its just not giving me the right graph.

```
usersSum <- cumsum(as.numeric(factor(someDat$users))); usersSum
plot(someDat$date,someDat$users, type= "b")
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong or whether its the right function to use. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
someDat <- read.table(text='     dates  users
11/06/2013  alfred
12/06/2013  andrew
12/06/2013  john
15/06/2013  jojo
15/06/2013  jeff
15/06/2013  samson
18/06/2013  dave
18/06/2013  hamsa
19/06/2013  kambua',header=TRUE)
someDat$cumsum <- 1:nrow(someDat)
someDat$date2 <- as.POSIXct(as.character(someDat$dates),format='%d/%m/%Y')
# as lines (left plot)
plot(someDat[!duplicated(someDat$dates, fromLast=TRUE),c('date2','cumsum')],type='l')
# as steps (right plot, following DWin)
plot(someDat[!duplicated(someDat$dates, fromLast=TRUE),c('date2','cumsum')],type='l')
```

[image] [image]